# Как поменять цвет тени и «делителя» у Spinner в Android?

Tags: android, java, style

Ка изменить цвет тени и divider в Spinner на API10, для API14 меняю вот так:

```
<style name="SpinnerDefaultTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:textColor">#F8F7F6</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#414141</item>
        <item name="android:divider">#2B2B2B</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Пробовал сделать так, но не работает

```
<style name="SpinnerItemDefaultTheme"  parent="android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F8F7F6</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#414141</item>
        <item name="android:divider">#2B2B2B</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Вот собственно конструктор темы:

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="@style/_DefaultTheme"/>
<style name="_DefaultTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemDefaultTheme</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerDefaultTheme</item>
</style>
```

Цвет тени которая сверху и снизу списка белая а не #414141, и делитель (divider) также белый, как исправить?